# Javascript - Put array items, including their duplicates, into a new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I couldn't find an answer to this specific question on S.O.

Let's say I have an array of strings, or in this case, numbers:

```
var x = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 3, 3, 5, 4, 5];
```

I'd like the output to be:

```
var output = [[1,1,1], [2], [3,3,3,3,3], [4], [5, 5, 5]];
```

I was hoping to use Lodash but most of that stuff tends to remove duplicates rather chunk them together into their own array.  Maybe some kind of `.map` iterator?

The order of the output doesn't really matter so much.  It just needs to chunk the duplicates into separate arrays that I'd like to keep.

Comment: so you want to group them ?

Comment: an array of strings? this is an array of integers the way you typed it.

Comment: If you're using lodash anyway, `grouper = _.flow([_.groupBy, _.values])` would be the function you're looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `reduce` to group the array elements into an object. Use `Object.values` to convert the object into an array.

```js
var x = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 3, 3, 5, 4, 5];
var result = Object.values(x.reduce((c, v) => {
  (c[v] = c[v] || []).push(v);
  return c;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

Shorter version:

```js
var x = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 3, 3, 5, 4, 5];
var result = Object.values(x.reduce((c, v) => ((c[v] = c[v] || []).push(v), c), {}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Aren't they starting with a flat array and trying to get a not-flat array?

Comment: OMG. Hahahah. I need more coffee

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) in a concise way like this:

```js
var x = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 3, 3, 5, 4, 5]

let result = x.reduce((r,c) => (r[c] = [...(r[c] || []), c],r), {})

console.log(Object.values(result))
```

The exact same with lodash would be:

```js
var x = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 3, 3, 5, 4, 5]

let result = _.values(_.groupBy(x))

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Using [`_.values`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#groupBy) to extract the values of the grouping object and [`_.groupBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#groupBy) to get the actual groupings

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array#prototype#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to group them:

```js
const x = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 3, 3, 5, 4, 5];

let helperObj = {};
const res = x.reduce((acc, curr) => {

  // If key is not present then add it
  if (!helperObj[curr]) {
    helperObj[curr] = curr;
    acc.push([curr]);
  }

  // Else find the index and push it
  else {
    let index = acc.findIndex(x => x[0] === curr);

    if (index !== -1) {
      acc[index].push(curr);
    }
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're hoping to use Lodash, you might be interested in [`groupBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#groupBy). It returns on object, but the `_.values` will give you the nested array:

```js
var x = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 3, 3, 5, 4, 5];
let groups = _.values(_.groupBy(x))
console.log(groups)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an imperative solution:

```js
var x = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 3, 3, 5, 4, 5];

x.sort();

var res = [];

for (const [i, n] of x.entries()) {
  if (n !== x[i-1]) res.push([n]);
  else res[res.length-1].push(n);
}

console.log(res);
```